# It’s empty; need a new one soon

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> My prefix is a vehicle or its part
>   Whose suffix‘s beauty uncertain
>   My suffix is raised apart
>   Its prefix frees a burden

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a

> **CARTRIDGE**.

My prefix is a vehicle or its part

> A CART can describe a vehicle, as in a go-kart, or a part of one, as in a shopping cart.

Whose suffix‘s beauty uncertain

> Beauty in ART is definitely subjective.

My suffix is raised apart

> A RIDGE is a raised part of a surface.

Its prefix frees a burden

> To be RID of something is to be free of its burden.

Title: It’s empty; need a new one soon

> When your printer's ink CARTRIDGEs become empty, you need new ones.